# Repeater PageCount and PageIndex

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asprepeater, page-index-changed

is there pageindex or pagecount for repeater? i able to do with gridview and could not find much with repeater and not in code-behind too, how would i do PageIndex and PageCount in Repeater?

```
 Page <%# rpt.PageIndex + 1 %> of <%# rpt.PageCount %>


<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpt_OnItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="rpt_OnItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
           <div >
                <div >
                     Page <%# rpt.PageIndex + 1 %> of <%# rpt.PageCount %>
                </div>
            </div>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate ......
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: No this does not exists. Repeater is too low-level for PageIndex and PageCount. Perhaps switching to ListView would be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeater control does not support paging out of the box, which means you have to implement it yourself. One way (and the easiest probably) is to use [PagedDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource.aspx) object, which encapsulates paging-related properties and logic. There is a couple of examples in web on how to accomplish this: [example one](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=345), [example two](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article980-paging-with-repeater-control-.aspx), [example three](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121644/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx).